# LONG column value

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having an issue with attempting to import data from an excel csv file. I am using SQL Developer 4.1. My problem is I keep getting an error of:

> ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

despite the fact that I am not using a `LONG` column. That is not even an option for me to use. I am only using `varchar2`, `number`, and `date`. Can somebody assist in explaining what the `LONG` thing is, and how I can get around it? And yes, I am aware of how stupid this sounds.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the other way around, i.e. you are trying to enter a number into the number column that is too high.   The Datatype is defined here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832

Comment: You mean, my data is longer than I have accounted for in the precision/character setup of the table? I do have an issue with data coming in (extracting it from another system) that looks like  '1.3785E17' for things, but I adjust those before attempting to import.